# Difference between Cast and Convert in C#

Tags: c#, decimal

I have a sql datareader...From which I have to fetch one decimal value.

What is the difference between

1. (decimal)datareader["percent"]

and

1. Convert.Todecimal(datareader["percent"])

And what are prons and cos ....of both methods.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Casting will succeed only if the object returned by `datareader["percent"]` is of the type `Decimal`.  Conversion will succeed when the object is of any type convertible to `Decimal`.  This includes `int`, `long`, `short`, etc.  Or more generally, anything that implements `IConvertible` and returns a useful value from `IConvertible.ToDecimal()` can be passed to `Convert.ToDecimal()`.

For example:

```
csharp> object a = (int)1;

csharp> a.GetType();
System.Int32

csharp> var dec = (decimal)a;
System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
  at Class3.Host (System.Object& $retval) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.CSharp.Evaluator.Evaluate (System.String input, System.Object& result, System.Boolean& result_set) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.CSharpShell.Evaluate (System.String input) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

csharp> var dec = Convert.ToDecimal(a);

csharp> dec;
1

csharp> dec.GetType();
System.Decimal
```

Comment: Howie, what kind of console are you using?  It looks like you have a powershell-like console allowing you to type in C# statements

Comment: @Harvey: It's the [Mono interactive C# shell](http://www.mono-project.com/CsharpRepl).

Comment: This is an excellent answer, although the explanation of cast is a little misleading. One can cast from say byte to int. It would be more accurate to say that casting works so long as the types are of the same category.

Comment: @IanC Not when unboxing.  When you have a value type boxed into an object, you must cast to *exactly* the same type of the boxed value in order to unbox it.  `(long)(object)(int)1` will always yield a runtime error, even though `(long)(int)1` would succeed.

Comment: Then how come `(decimal)value` works when value is a `double`?

Comment: @NigelTouch That will only work when the expression `value` is typed `double` -- that is, it is not an unboxing operation. If `value` is typed `object` then the `double` value is boxed, and you can only cast it to `double`. A boxed value object can only be unboxed into its exact value type. (Try this: `(decimal)(object)1.0`. You will get an InvalidCastException. [See this ideone](http://ideone.com/WvsYBv).)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about decimal specifically, but I know that for integers Convert rounds whereas casting truncates, i.e. (int)7.6 is 7, Convert.ToInt32(7.6) is 8.  Not directly applicable to your example, but good to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

The first (`(decimal)datareader["percent"]`) is an explicit conversion (cast). What it does is that it causes the compiler to unbox or cast the target value (`datareader["percent"]`) to a `decimal`. This will cause an `InvalidCastException` unless `datareader["percent"]` is a `decimal` or a boxed `decimal`.

The second runs code that is part of .NET which checks what kind of object `datareader["percent"]` is, and tries to convert it to a `decimal` in an appropriate way. This will succeed if the value is any kind of number, (e.g. an `int`).

Comment: Then how come `(decimal)value` works when value is a `double`?

Comment: @NigelTouch: `(decimal)value` is a conversion, which works. `(decimal)(object)value` is incorrect unboxing (the `double` is first boxed into an `object`) and throws. `(double)(object)value` is correct unboxing and works.

Answer (score 1):

A couple good answers here, but since you mentioned a SqlDataReader, you've got the GetDecimal() method instead of using the reader["columnName"] indexer syntax. I don't know if it will buy you any performance, but it gives you type safety without using Convert or casting.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Casting is saying that the object is of type (or a derivative). Convert is saying that though it may not be that type or derivative, there exists a way of turning in to the destination type.

e.g.

```
string a = "1234";
object b = a;

// success, a is really a string
string c = (string)b;

// fails because b is not actually an int
int d = (int)b;

// success because there is way to convert the numeric string to an int
int e = Convert.ToInt32(b);
```

*EDIT: Good point @cdhowie, Freudian slip. This should be a little more descriptive*

Comment: Convert **will not** return the default value of the type on an error: `Convert.ToDecimal(new object());` -->
System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.

Comment: Fixed, think i was thinking about TryParse while I was writing the first version. Either way, should be more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

If in question type is nullable, then it gets for `0` for all digit-type types conversions.
For example, all the following returns `0`

```
Convert.ToByte(null);
Convert.ToDecimal(null);
Convert.ToDouble(null);
Convert.ToInt64(null);
Convert.ToInt32(null);
```

But instead, if casting is applied, `InvalidOperationException` is thrown,  saying *Nullable object must have a value*.